# swift page view controller gradient

Tags: ios, swift

it's based by apple's pageviewcontroller.
there is two viewcontroller. rootview, pageview controller.
i need to do when pageview is flip(?) page, change gradient color of rootview's sublayer.
here is my change gradeient function

```
func changeGradient(){
    repeat {
        randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(StartColorcarr.count)))

    } while randomIndex == lastIndex
    lastIndex = randomIndex

    self.gradient.colors = [
        UIColor(netHex:(self.StartColorcarr[self.randomIndex])).cgColor,
        UIColor(netHex:(self.EndColorcarr[self.randomIndex])).cgColor
    ]
}
```

this is model controller

```
func indexOfViewController(_ viewController: DataViewController) -> Int {
    // Return the index of the given data view controller.
    // For simplicity, this implementation uses a static array of model objects and the view controller stores the model object; you can therefore use the model object to identify the index.
    return pageData.index(of: viewController.dataObject) ?? NSNotFound
}
```

i think this is function when page was scroll.
my question. 
i can't call function in Rootviewcontroller at ModelController or DataviewController.

```
    gradient.frame = view.bounds
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
    gradient.colors = [
        UIColor(netHex:(0x2a5cdc)).cgColor,
        UIColor(netHex:(0x13e999)).cgColor
    ]
    gradient.frame = self.view.bounds
    self.view.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
```

this is sublayer of RootviewController, how i made
so please help me and save me
god help us all